# Scala: how to inherit a "static slot"?

Tags: inheritance, scala, static

Well, I'm learning Scala so this question may be too basic for most people.

In Java I can have a static slot (function or variable) in a class, and then I will have that slot in inherited classes too.

In Scala I don't have static slots, but I have companion objects. But I'm finding out that those objects are not part of the inherited class, so if I have two classes `Person` and `Student`, and Person has a companion object with a variable `all:List` that returns a list of all persons so I can do `Person.all`, I was expecting that I could do `Student.all` too, but that's not the case.

Is there any way to get the same behaviour that I would get in java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Theoretically speaking, Java's behavior in this respect is *very* broken.  The fact that subclasses inherit static members really doesn't make any sense from an object-oriented point of view.  Statics are really nothing more than fancy, scoped globals.  Inheritance is something you see at the class level, but statics really aren't at the class level (since they're global) so inheritance shouldn't apply.  The fact that it does in Java is...disturbing.

Scala has really taken the high road in this department; something for which we should all be grateful.  As mentioned in another answer, the correct way to define "inherited" statics is to extract the inherited members out into a trait:

```
trait Inherited {
  def foo() { ... }
  def bar(i: Int) = ...
}

class Person {
  ...
}

object Person extends Inherited

class Student extends Person {
  ...
}

object Student extends Inherited
```

It may seem needlessly more verbose than Java, but trust me when I say that the semantics are a lot less surprising as a result.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is what you meant, but a companion object can extend from some traits/classes:

```
class Person
class Student extends Person

trait Aggregation[T] {
  val all: List[T]
}

object Person extends Aggregation[Person] {
  val all: List[Person] = List(new Person, new Person)
}

object Student extends Aggregation[Student] {
  val all: List[Student] = List(new Student, new Student)
}

println(Person.all) // prints all persons
println(Student.all) // prints all students
```

Answer (score 4):

Objects in Scala are not class-level entities like statics are in Java. They are simply a class definition and singleton instantiation rolled into one.

A companion object is a special case that allows the sharing of private data between it and its companion class.

Objects can extend classes, but not other objects. After all an 'object' is just a singleton instance - the class definition of an 'object' is hidden.

Is it reasonable to expect the special relationship between companion objects and companion classes to project an additional class hierarchy on companion objects?

I suspect the best way to achieve a dependency between Person and Student is to delegate.

```
object Person { val all = List(1,2,3) }
object Student { val all = Person.all.filter(_ % 2 == 0) }
```

Answer (score -1):

Afaics, Daniel Spiewak's and Walter Chang's answers appear to provide two separate copies of the `all` list. I didn't test the following, but I hope this provides the correct outline even it if has errors.

```
class Person
class Student extends Person

object Person {
  val all: List[Person]
}
```

then within `Student`, access via `Person.all`

If you want to provide access via `Student.all` then

```
object Student {
  def all() = Person.all
}
```

Another way to do it, would allow you to declare the statics (i.e singleton object) in a trait to be inherited.

```
trait StaticAll {
   object Static { val all: List[Person] }
}

class Person extends StaticAll
class Student extends Person
```

Then access with `StaticAll#Static.all`. I think that is correct and not `StaticAll.Static.all`. Again this is all off the top of my head, I didn't test any this. Please correct my errors.

Comment: The error is that there are two separate copies of the list. The fact is, all is not a list, but a reference. You're welcome.

Comment: I was fairly new to Scala when I wrote this comment. I realize now that Walter Chang's trait declares an uninitialized reference, thus there his code does not 2 copies of the list. In my code, I forget to initialize the val List[Person] = List(). With that change, would my code be correct?