# Scala can not resolve inherited Java interface constant members

Tags: java, oop, scala, interface

Class hierarchy in Java:

Interface: *Cluster*, *Classify*

Class *Kluster* hierarchy is show below

```
Cluster  <- ,
            +-- Kluster
Classify <- '
```

File: **oop/Cluster.java**

```
package oop;

public interface Cluster {
    public String HELLO = "hello";
}
```

File: **oop/Kluster.java**

```
package oop;

interface Classify {
    public String GOODBYE = "good bye";
}

public class Kluster implements Cluster, Classify {

}
```

File: **oop/KlusterMain.java**

```
package oop;

public class KlusterMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Kluster.HELLO);
        System.out.println(Kluster.GOODBYE);
    }
}
```

Till now everything works as expected. I can print HELLO and GOODBYE constants.

Now when I try to access them from Scala compiler, it gives error.

File: **oop/cluster.scala**

```
package oop

object cluster {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val k = new Kluster
    println(Cluster.HELLO)
    println(Classify.GOODBYE)
    println(Kluster.HELLO) // <- this is the problematic line
  }
}
```

ERRORs:

```
Scala Problem
value HELLO is not a member of object oop.Kluster
/scala-snippets/src/main/scala/oop/cluster.scala
line 8
```

Why can't Scala resolve the hierarchy that *Kluster* object implements both *Cluster* and *Classify* interfaces ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do know that putting constants into interfaces to use them in implementing classes is bad approach, don't you? In Java you use `final` class with private constructor and use `import static` to shorten constant names, if needed. In Scala you use `object`s and imports. But Scala does not have notion of static fields - it has objects instead which participate in inheritance properly. It was impossible to unify static fields from Java with proper object-oriented system, so in Scala you can't use static members (fields and methods) from subclasses.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586764/scala-how-to-inherit-a-static-slot).

Comment: Of course, I do. This is a simplified code from Apache Mahout 0.7 code-base. I was trying to use same from Scala.

Comment: Scala is supposed to be compatible with Java. I guess there are more incompatibilities b/w Scala and Java.

Comment: Yes, Scala is supposed (and in fact is) compatible with Java. The level of compatibility is the question. Several design decisions in Java cannot be supported in Scala in a sane way, without breaking something, so these parts of Java were deemed not very important, and Scala does not support them. One of such features is static inheritance. Scala does not have notion of static, and inheriting static members is a very rare use case in Java, so it is not supported in Scala.