# Scala: Inheritance of static methods vs. DRY-principle vs. encapsulation

Tags: scala, oop

I am trying to implement an OOP-paradigm in Scala. I am going to have one abstract base class with 50-100 subclasses. Each of those subclasses should be able to generate some random instances for testing purposes. (In fact my real life scenario is quite a bit more involved than that, but I think it will suffice for this question.)

No matter how I go about it, I am dissatisfied with the solution. I hope some of you Scala experts can help me think about this problem the Scala way.

If statics were allowed in Scala, I would be doing something like:

```
abstract class Base {
  protected val instanceValues: List[SomeType] // i.e. row-number, full-URL etc.
  def toString():String = "Base[" + classValues.toString() + "]: " + instanceValues.toString()
  protected static def classValues: SomeOtherType // i.e. table-name, domain-name etc.
  static def genData(): List[Base] = /* some default implementation using only classValues */
}

class A(override val instanceValues: List[SomeType]) extends Base {
  protected static def classValues = new SomeType(/* A-specific */)
}

...

class Z(override val instanceValues: List[SomeType]) extends Base {
  protected static def classValues = new SomeType(/* Z-specific */)
}

class SpecialCase(override val instanceValues: List[SomeType]) extends Base {
  protected protected def classValues = new SomeType(/* SpecialCase-specific */)
  override static def genData(): List[Base] = /* something specific to this subclass not easily expressed elegantly using classValues */
}
```

But, as statics are not allowed in Scala, was never really a solution.

Reading things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1587046/1506348) (note: This question is not a duplicate of that one - this deals with the inelegancy - as I see it - of using the companion objects solution) it would instead appear that I need to create 28 identical companion objects to house the classValues- and genData-methods:

```
abstract class Base {
  protected val instanceValues: List[SomeType]
}

class A(override val instanceValues: List[SomeType]) extends Base {
  def toString():String = "Base[" + A.classValues.toString() + "]: " + instanceValues.toString()
}
object A {
  private val classValues: SomeOtherType
  static def genData(): List[Base] = /* some default implementation using only classValues */
}

...

class Z(override val instanceValues: List[SomeType]) extends Base {
  def toString():String = "Base[" + Z.classValues.toString() + "]: " + instanceValues.toString()
}
object Z {
  private val classValues: SomeOtherType
  static def genData(): List[Base] = /* some default implementation using only classValues */
}

class SpecialCase(override val instanceValues: List[SomeType]) extends Base {
  def toString():String = "Base[" + SpecialCase.classValues.toString() + "]: " + instanceValues.toString()
}
object SpecialCase {
  private val classValues: SomeOtherType
  static def genData(): List[Base] = /* something specific for SpecialCase */
}
```

Besides having quite a lot of bloat, this solution seems to violate the DRY-principle, and it forced me to re-implement the shared toString-method in a near-identical manner too. Finally it means that anyone extending Base, should remember to add a companion object for the new class.

A different solution, is to have a "test data"-factory:

```
abstract class Base {
  val instanceValues: List[SomeType]
  def classValues: SomeOtherType
  def toString():String = "Base[" + classValues.toString() + "]: " + instanceValues.toString()
}

object TestDataGenerator {
  def genData(clss:String): List[Base] = clss match {
    case "SpecialCase" => /* something specific to SpecialCase */
    case other => /* some default implementation using reflection for creation and some kind of manipulation of the SomeType and SomeOtherType objects after creation */
  }
}

class A(override val instanceValues: List[SomeType]) extends Base {
  def classValues = new SomeType(/* A-specific */)
}

...

class Z(override val instanceValues: List[SomeType]) extends Base {
  def classValues = new SomeType(/* Z-specific */)
}

class SpecialCase(override val instanceValues: List[SomeType]) extends Base {
  def classValues = new SomeType(/* SpecialCase-specific */)
}
```

But this requires me to open up read access to the fields instanceValues and classValues, which is not desirable.

Comment: This can be solved easily by using algebraic data types. Google that term. When I get more time I will post a solution, if no one else has in the meantime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala: how to inherit a "static slot"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586764/scala-how-to-inherit-a-static-slot)

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of that one. That one deals with how to do "statics" in Scala in general. This deals with the inelegancy - as I see it - of using the companion objects solution for my use case.

Comment: @I.K. I have read up on algebraic data types, and interesting as they were, I cannot see how they would help out here, so I sure hope you will be able to get more time to post at some point.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: I ended up changing my architecture to consist of traits and objects, with "overriden" inner classes for creating instances. It's not a whole lot of beauty, but at least I am avoiding the deficiencies listed in the question.